# Package contains object and package with same name

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, jenkins, maven-3

I am having problems compiling some Scala with Maven or Eclipse where I try to import a class from a Java jar which contains both a namespace and class of the same name.
I can compile with `scalac`, however.

E.g. the Java project (jar) contains:

```
src/foo/bar.java

src/foo/bar/some_resource.txt

-> foobar.jar

Scala project references foobar.jar

Foobartest.scala:

import foo.bar

class foobartest {

}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
package foo contains object and package with same name: bar 
one of them needs to be removed from classpath
```

Using Maven 3.0.03/Eclipse 3.7.1 with Scala 2.9.0.1 (and `maven-scala-plugin`).

The jar which I am having problems with is `jenkins-core-1.399.jar` - it definitely contains several instances where there is a namespace and object of the same name.
I am attempting to write a Jenkins plugin in Scala (I could do this in Java but would prefer scala since all of our libraries are in scala), which is dependent on using Maven -
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial.

Comment: Hey did you ever get a Jenkins plugin written in Scala? I'm trying the same

Comment: Yes, its on my github. I tried to publish it but I didn't get great support from the jenkins people to be honest. https://github.com/Chemmo/scala_plugin

Comment: I wrote one too and did get it published, but not downloadable from the plugin manager https://github.com/jenkinsci/hello-world-scala-plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That kind of limitation was outlined in [SI-4695: package object misbehaves in the presence of classfiles](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4695).

As suggested in [SI-2089 (naming restriction makes some jars unusable)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2089), you could try and use the "`resolve-term-conflict`", as implemented in [changeset 25145](https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/changelog/scala-svn?cs=25145):

> Added a `-Y` option to resolve namespace collisions between package and object.
>   It's a blunt instrument: if people have lots of these conflicts they need to resolve in individually nuanced fashion, they'll probably remain out of luck.

```
val termConflict  = ChoiceSetting     ("-Yresolve-term-conflict", "strategy", "Resolve term conflicts", 113 List("package", "object", "error"), "error")

// Some jars (often, obfuscated ones) include a package and
// object with the same name. Rather than render them unusable,
// offer a setting to resolve the conflict one way or the other.
// This was motivated by the desire to use YourKit probes, which
// require `yjp.jar` at runtime. See SI-2089.
```

Comment: What is equivalent options in maven for it?

Comment: @Saurabh I have not found any immediate obvious maven equivalent option.

Comment: I got it, have added here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51495053/1610034.

Answer (score 7):

The actual compiler option is "-Yresolve-term-conflict:**strategy**" where strategy is either package, object, error.

Comment: What is equivalent options in maven for it?