# package cats contains object and package with same name: implicits

Tags: scala, scala-cats, ammonite

Heard about the new Cats-Effect library here

http://typelevel.org/blog/2017/05/02/io-monad-for-cats.html

Immidiately added the following line to my ammonite shell predef.sc

```
interp.load.ivy("org.typelevel" % "cats-core_2.12" % "0.9.0")
interp.load.ivy( "org.typelevel" % "cats-effect_2.12" % "0.1-0848c9b")
```

Now when I load my ammonite shell. I get error

```
cmd0.sc:1: package cats contains object and package with same name: implicits
one of them needs to be removed from classpath
import cats.effect.IO
       ^
Compilation Failed
```

Googled and found a solution here

[Package contains object and package with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984730/package-contains-object-and-package-with-same-name)

But I wonder how can I apply the `-Yresolve-term-conflict:strategy` to the ammonite shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself. Here are the right imports

```
interp.load.ivy("org.typelevel" %% "cats" % "0.9.0")
interp.load.ivy( "org.typelevel" % "cats-effect_2.12" % "0.1-0848c9b")
```

Now everything works fine

```
@ import cats._
import cats._
@ import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.IO
@
```