# Compile Error when killing topology from storm bolt programatically: object and package with same name

Tags: scala, maven, compiler-errors, sbt, apache-storm

I was looking for how to kill a topology from a storm bolt in storm `1.2.1` in my scala project.
From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134473/1610034), I wrote following code to do it:

```
  private def shutTopology(){
    import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils
    import org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient
    val conf = Utils.readStormConfig
    val nimbusClient = 
NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(conf).getClient
    nimbusClient.deactivate(topology_name)
  }
```

But it given following error in line: `val conf = Utils.readStormConfig`, How to resolve this?

> Error:(46, 17) package daemon contains object and package with same name: nimbus
>
> one of them needs to be removed from classpath
>
> val conf = Utils.readStormConfig

I get above error by compiling via both `sbt` and `mvn`. I see some description for this [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5334.html) but not much help on how to resolve this.

### Edit:

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986603/1610034), I was able to compile this in `sbt` using following `scalac` options:

```
"-Yresolve-term-conflict:object"
```

I am stil not able to get this done how to resolve this error when compiling with maven.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986603/1610034), I was able to compile this in sbt using following scalac options:

```
"-Yresolve-term-conflict:object"
```

to get this compiled with maven, I did following changes in my pom.xml as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23138361/1610034):

```
<configuration>
      <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
      <args>
        <arg>-Yresolve-term-conflict:object</arg> //this was added
      </args>
      <jvmArgs>
        <jvmArg>-Xms2048m</jvmArg>
        <jvmArg>-Xmx4096m</jvmArg>
      </jvmArgs>
</configuration>
```